# Xcode profiler: sigprocmask & __sigaltstack overhead

Tags: xcode, codenameone, profiler, overhead, sigprocmask

I am profiling my app (built with Codename One) using Xcode and an iPhone X device. I notice that, during heavy calculations (single- or multithreaded), `sigprocmask` and `__sigaltstack` (from `libsystem_kernel.dylib`) are the biggest time consumers with **more than 20% each**. That is a huge overhead. Does anyone know where this is coming from and if there is a way to reduce the overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a huge expert on these but as far as I can tell they're low level kernel calls. I think both of these are profiler overhead so they won't be the top of the list if you run without a profiler.

Again, not an expert but this makes sense. The profiler needs to find out stuff about the current method and stack periodically.

Comment: Thanks, yes that must be it. (I probably should have checked Call Tree > Hide system libraries.) At first I thought that the performance difference between profiling and running was only about 10-20%, but it appears that I also have to take the thermal state of the device into account, with runs of 1-2 minutes using 6 threads. Carefully testing (letting the device cool down after every run) I find an average performance difference of 40% between 'build for profiling; profile' and 'build for running; install; run'. That explains almost exactly the 2x 20% for the system functions when profiling.